# DWG file does not show up in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Forge Viewer, tested with both Viewer version 2.17 and 4.0, but cannot view DWG files. Those same DWG files can view in Autodesk Viewer (https://viewer.autodesk.com/). I checked all the files were uploaded successfully to my Forge bucket and they return appropriate URNs. However the Viewer returns error 404 (not found) at https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/{{urn}}

My app can view DWF files perfectly, but DWG files cannot. I don't know what is the difference since they use the same code to upload and view.

I checked the Forge API was updated to use hub, my code uses only storage location. I don't know it will make something difference or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Khoa Ho, With my experience, 404 means the corresponding dataset of translation does not exist. Have you checked the translation status if it tells something weird? In addition, does this issue happen with specific drawing, or any DWG at your side?

Comment: I found the problem, my web app can show AutoCAD 2010 and 2011 files (AC1024 DWG tag), but AC1027 and AC1032 DWG tags (from AutoCAD 2013 and above) do not show up in my Forge viewer, they return either error 5 or 9. Is there a issue with AutoCAD file versions?

Comment: There is also the same error with DWFX file format, it returns error 9. While DWF file works fine in Forge viewer.

Comment: so can I understand you loaded some DWG of AutoCAD 2010 and 2011, and aggregated with some other DWGs of release 2013 and above? Or you simply means you loaded the DWGs of specific version separately? i would appreciate if you could share the demo copy of the DWGs.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang I need to go back with this issue again. I don't know why my DWG files uploaded in bucket do not translated to view, While those same files are viewable in Autodesk Viewer. I am thinking Autodesk Viewer (https://viewer.autodesk.com/) uses hub and project to store DWG files that makes the difference with DWG files in my bucket.

Comment: my apology! I missed your update. Did you try to log a new case and get any reply from my colleagues? if not, I will follow up further.  yes, viewer.autodesk.com has its management, the infrastructure also uses Forge Data Management API. However, this will not affect file translation. When you said 'not viewable', could you check browser console if any error ? this assumes the translation succeeded

Comment: @XiaodongLiang This issue was solved a long time back. The problem is not related to AutoCAD files. But the filename should not contain special characters when uploading to Forge storage which is Linux based. I am sorry to miss the update here.

Comment: thank you much for sharing the experience. it sounds you did not URL encoded the file name when uploading to Forge storage. yes, this might cause problem with the translation. glad to know you found the problem.